Accurately Fetching Complete Dataset from a Large Table in Cassandra
I have a Cassandra table containing over 450,000 rows. When attempting to fetch all the rows, I consistently receive slightly fewer results, for example, 448,546. For certain use cases, I need to retrieve the entire dataset in one go. What strategies or configurations can ensure that I can accurately fetch all rows from this large dataset? Any advice on handling large-scale data retrieval in Cassandra would be appreciated.
I am using Python's cassandra-driver, I tried something like this:
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class User(Model):
    username = Text(primary_key=True)
    fullname = Text(required=True)
    email = Text(required=True)
    phone_number = Text(required=True)
    password = Text(required=True)
    address = Text()
    birth_day = Date()
    branch = Text()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_data = User.objects.limit(500000)


DSBulk is probably the best option for something like this. It also has the ability to "count" the rows in a table with pretty fair accuracy.
You can download DSBulk from here: https://downloads.datastax.com/#bulk-loader
Here is a simple example of unloading the nerd_holidays table from the stackoverflow keyspace to the nerd_holidays.csv file:
dsbulk unload -url nerd_holidays.csv -k stackoverflow -t nerd_holidays -header true
            -m 'year_bucket=year_bucket, event_date=event_date, id=id, name=name'

You can find more information on it in the DataStax docs.
